# JavaScript Defined "In-Button" Validating Multiple Input Fields

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in Javascript and got along the following problem which doesn't yet work as expected and I would like to ask the community for help. Basically, I have a (uncertain, build up on the run, here for simplicity only 2) number of (number) input fields and I want to validate whether the value entered is between 0 and 10.

I can only use pure JavaScript and such "in button" definition of a JavaScript function. Thx for any comments!

```
<p> Please enter a value 0 and 10. </p>

   <input class="offers" type="number" step="0.01" id='1'> 

<p> Please enter another value between 0 and 10. </p>

   <input class="offers" type="number" step="0.01" id='2'>   



 <input type="submit" name="OutterButton"  id="absenden" style="display: none">

        <input type="button" value="Absenden" onclick="function testOffer() {

             var offers = document.getElementsByClassName('offers');

             for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++){
                 var offer = document.getElementById(offers[i]).value;

                 if (offer>=10 != offer<=0)   
                   { alert('Wrong Number'); }
                 else if ( isNaN(offer) ) 
                   { alert('Please enter a number).'); } 
             }
             }
             else{var subButton = document.getElementsByName('OutterButton')[0];
                 subButton.style.display='inline'; subButton.click();
                 subButton.style.display='none'}}; testOffer();">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using the `<script>` tag?

```
<script>
function testOffer() {
         var offers = document.getElementsByClassName('offers');
         for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++){
             var offer = document.getElementById(offers[i]).value;
             if (offer>=10 != offer<=0)   
               { alert('Wrong Number'); }
             else if ( isNaN(offer) ) 
               { alert('Please enter a number).'); } 
         }
 }  ...
</script>
<input type="button" value="Absenden" onclick="testOffer()" />
```

---

Yes, there is a problem in your Javascript. Because it is embeded, it is hard to debug. But here the problem:

```
function testOffer() {
    var offers = document.getElementsByClassName('offers');

    for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++){
        var offer = document.getElementById(offers[i]).value;

        if (offer>=10 != offer<=0)
        { alert('Wrong Number'); }
        else if ( isNaN(offer) )
        { alert('Please enter a number).'); }
    }
}
else{var subButton = document.getElementsByName('OutterButton')[0];
     subButton.style.display='inline'; subButton.click();
     subButton.style.display='none'}}; testOffer();
```

As you can see, the `else` statement comes from nowhere. The function definition is complete just before the `else`.

Comment: thx, unfortunately I can't, because the framework (webserver) I'm using for some reason doesn't support it. So it's prolly not optimal, but my way is a workaround.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you the problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: I see the problem and I've to learn more about the syntax. Only needed a few lines of Javascript so far. Thx a lot, appreciate!